# How to fix blank screen in a VGA switcher?

Tags: vga, switch, desktop-computer, ps4

I just now bought a Köning VGA switch (Model name:CMP-SWITCH51), for I can SWITCH between my monitor and my ps4.

The first problem was, a out of range message, which came from my video card, but after I set the HZ number to 60, its looks like everything fine, because I get back my Windows screen, but something strange happened.

After I get backed my computer screen, the ps4 screen just gone and never came back on switch (But its worked standalone with Hama hdmi Vga adapter).

How can I fix this problem?

Solutions what I tried:

- Set to my ps4 to lower resolution
- Set to the range limit to limited
- I pushed auto button in my monitor
- I tried unplugging computer D-dub cable from the switch, but it's just doesn't work
- I tried switch cable, not worked either

Comment: Set resolution and refresh rate (Hz) the same on both PS4 and PC

Comment: @LSxCPU I can't, ps4 not give any option for that.